# How to simplify Nested Conditionals?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

I think that using if / if else statement is too much code, I saw on some websites that are better to simplify nested conditions like some examples that shows on this website   https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-if-else/

I was thinking to get the wind direction names in an array or an object like this - let windNames = [Northerly','North Easterly','Easterly','South Easterly'...]

Can you guys help me out?

Many thanks.

```js
function textDescription(d) {
    { //convert the wind direction as int to string
        if (d > 0 && d < 20) {
            return "Northerly";
        } else if (d > 30 && d < 60) {
            return "North easterly";
        } else if (d > 55 && d < 100) {
            return "Easterly";
        } else if (d > 110 && d < 140) {
            return "South easterly";
        } else if (d > 145 && d < 201) {
            return "Southerly";
        } else if (d > 201 && d < 215) {
            return "South westerly";
        } else if (d > 235 && d < 245) {
            return "Westerly";
        } else if (d > 225 && d < 325) {
            return "North westerly";
        } else if (d > 321) {
            return "Northerly";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion there is actually nothing wrong with using if-else here

Comment: You do know that North should really be `337.5` to `22.5`, right?

Answer (score 6):

You could use an array of arrays, where each sub-array indicates the two numbers `d` must be between, and the associated string. When the function is called, `.find` the associated sub-array, and return its string if it exists:

```js
const windDirections = [
  [0, 20, 'Northerly'],
  [30, 60, 'North easterly'],
  [55, 100, 'Easterly'],
  [110, 140, 'South easterly'],
  [145, 201, 'Southerly'],
  [201, 215, 'South westerly'],
  [235, 245, 'Westerly'],
  [225, 325, 'North westerly'],
  [321, Infinity, 'Northerly'],
];
function textDescription(d) {
  const foundDirectionArr = windDirections.find(([low, high]) => d > low && d < high);
  if (foundDirectionArr) {
    return foundDirectionArr[2];
  }
}

console.log(textDescription(208));
console.log(textDescription(326));
```

Comment: Wow I get it. I was literally trying to figure out where should I do with the numbers.  I even tried to use the argument ` d += 22.5;`  and parse a string argument
  `let which = parseInt(degree / 45);`
  `return sectors[which%8];`

Comment: Something like that would be more elegant, but it'd only be possible if the direction ranges were even - but they aren't, they're very uneven. One range is 20, another is 30, another 45, another 56, another 14, etc... Now, if they were all 45 or something, then that general approach would work

Comment: Can I ask you.. how did you get those values in the console.log? (326) and (208)?

Comment: I just picked some random numbers to show an example.